# How do I format the list of figures to show like Figure 3-4 : Caption

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: i want output like this]

I need the list of figures entries to look like the above picture. I have used formatting in the captioned image but it wont show. I also tried:

```tex
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\textbf{Fig. }}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnumb}{\quad}
```

Some code I have used is:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}   
\usepackage{tocloft}       
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic {figure}\hspace{.3em}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
\begin{document} 
\newpage
{
\listoffigures
}
\newpage
\section{intro}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{This is figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The only odd thing is the `\space` or `~` before the colon.  Is the figure label the same, or is it just in the LOF?

Comment: See also `\DeclareCaptionFormat` and `\DeclareCaptionListFormat` from the caption package.

Comment: jonh i used \declareCapationListFormat it worked for some manner and gives output as i wanted but it comes with some indentation . how do i remove that

Comment: It could be a lot of things.  Adding a second MWE would help.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using the commands provided by the package `tocloft`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}   
\usepackage{tocloft}  % needed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<     
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic {figure}\hspace{.3em}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}

%************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename~}% before the figure number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}% after figure number
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}% no indent
\newlength{\extrawidth}% extra width of the box with the figure number
\settowidth{\extrawidth}{\cftfigpresnum} % 
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\extrawidth} % add the extra width
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{1.0}% dot separation
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\bigskip}
%**************************************

\begin{document} 
    \newpage
    {
        \listoffigures
    }
    \newpage
    \section{intro}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{This is figure}
    \end{figure}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{10}% test 2-digit page number
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{This is another figure}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

See section 2.3 of the [Package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) for more details.